# Angular Pagination : Display a set of A4 sized pages

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, pagination

I am working on pagination using NgbdPaginationBasic
app.module.ts

```
import { NgbdPaginationBasic } from './pagination-basic';
```

I need to create a set of pages in A4 size with Header and Footer visible only in the first two pages. I have applied pagination on the body only
app.html

```
    <table class="table">
      <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>email</th>
      </tr>
      <tr *ngFor="let item of data | slice: (page-1) * pageSize : (page-1) * pageSize + pageSize">
        <td>{{item.id}}</td>
        <td>{{item.first_name}}{{item.last_name}}</td>
        <td>{{item.email}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Here is a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-pagination-kxfhcc) I created for demonstration. The pagination is working fine on the body but the Header and Footer I want them to be hidden after the 2nd page.

Is there a way to do it or any other tool or thing I can use? All three parts of the page(header,body,footer) should have the same pagination tag.

Comment: Just add `*ngIf="page < 3"` to the header / footer div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `*ngIf`, for ex.:

```
  <div style="border:1px solid black;margin-bottom:4px" *ngIf="page <= 2"> <---
    <hr/><span> HEADER </span><hr/>...
```

Your code:

```
<div>
  <div style="border:1px solid black;margin-bottom:4px" *ngIf="page <= 2">
    <hr/><span> HEADER </span><hr/>
                            <div class="intro mt-3 ml-3">
                            <span>John Doe</span>
                            <br/>
                            <span>99/123.342 LAT Street</span>
                            <br/>
                            <span>Mars Community</span>
                            <br/>
                            <span>XYZ Country</span>
                            <br/>
                            <span>Ph. 123243423423</span>
                            <br/>
                            <br/>
                            <span class="mt-2">Dear John</span>
                            <br/>
                        </div>
  </div>
  <div style="border: 1px solid red">
    <hr/><span style="color : navy">MAIN BODY</span><hr/>
    <table class="table">
      <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>email</th>
      </tr>
      <tr *ngFor="let item of data | slice: (page-1) * pageSize : (page-1) * pageSize + pageSize">
        <td>{{item.id}}</td>
        <td>{{item.first_name}}{{item.last_name}}</td>
        <td>{{item.email}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div style="border :1px solid black;margin-top:3px" *ngIf="page <= 2">
    <hr/><span> Footer </span><hr/>
    <p><strong>PLEASE READ THIS</strong><p>
    <span>THIS IS THE FOOTER. HEADER AND FOOTER TO BE DISPLAYED FOR PAGES 1 and 2 ONLY </span>
  </div>


<div>
<ngb-pagination [pageSize]="25" [collectionSize]="100" [(page)]="page" aria-label="Default pagination"></ngb-pagination>
<hr>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks man, but can I set the dimensions to that of an A4 page. like how can I set custom height and width?